# It seems that tail is buffering though -f option is set

Tags: bash, grep, pipe, tail, buffering

I am writing a script for log parsing, made up with piped tail and grep commands.
For line numbering purpose, I use a command line which looks like (simplified) :

`tail file_path -f|grep -n "" --line-buffered |tail -n +5|grep -E 'regexpr'`

however in that case, the -f option since to be inoperative (tried `echo pattern>>file_path` in a separate terminal)

however, if I change my command to

`tail file_path -f|grep -n "" --line-buffered |cat|grep -E 'regexpr'`

then it works. It seems that the second tail command (with +n option to filter first lines) is buffering

Any idea would be great !

Comment: BTW, `tail -n +5` is easily replaced with `{ for ((i=0; i<=5; i++)); do read _ || break; done; cat; }` in your pipeline.

Comment: yes thank you, I had this solution with a while loop but but I work with big log file.s Therefore I want to avoid bash loop and rather use piped command, it's much faster.

Comment: A loop is fine if it's only looping for the five lines it needs to ignore. Once it hands off to `cat` the performance for the rest of the file is as fast as it would have been without any loop at all. What's slow is if you use a bash loop for your whole file, but that isn't what the comment above recommends.

Comment: BTW, you can replace _both_ the `tail -n +5` and the `grep -E 'regexpr'` with a single awk command: `awk '/regexpr/ && NR>5'`

Comment: To be a little more clear what my first comment advised: `tail file_path -f|grep -n "" --line-buffered | { for ((i=0; i<=5; i++)); do read _ || break; done; cat; } | grep -E 'regexpr'` -- see how the (slow) bash `read` command is only ever called five times, no matter how long your input is.

Comment: sometimes I need to loop not on 5 lines but on 100k lines or more, this is what makes it slower. I'm gonna try with an awk - never used that command yet

Comment: I solved my issue using stdbuf -oL : tail file_path -f|grep -n "" --line-buffered | stdbuf -oL tail -n +5|grep -E 'regexpr'. The awk was a working solution but slower than tail|grep. Thank you !

Comment: Ah. I misread what you wanted -- thought you wanted to _skip_ five lines and use the rest, not take five lines.

Comment: BTW, please add answers with the "Add an Answer" / "Post Your Answer" button, not with a comment. That way people can comment / vote / edit the answer separate from the question itself, and you'll after a delay be allowed to "accept" the answer, which will mark your question solved (and instruct the site to present the question/answer pair to people with similar problems).

Comment: @toubab please consider adding an answer of your stdbuf -oL solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue using stdbuf -oL :

```
tail file_path -f|grep -n "" --line-buffered | stdbuf -oL tail -n +5|grep -E 'regexpr'
```

The awk was a working solution but slower than tail|grep